# fakeroot make-kpkg buildpackage

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, fakeroot

When I run

```
make-kpkg --initrd buildpackage
```

with concurrency_level set to 17, all cores are at 100% according to gnome-system-monitor, when running the cc1-jobs.

When I run

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd buildpackage
```

with concurrency_level set to 17 as well, the cores stay at around 40-60%.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I have to use fakeroot-ng?

p.s.:
The xsltproc-jobs take 100%, btw. I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd kernel_image kernel_headers kernel_source kernel_manual kernel_debug
```

is the way to go.

I don't know why

```
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd buildpackage
```

has problems.